# IsShowingUser not working in Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.forms

i'm developing an app based on maps.
Here my problem is i'm **not able** to display user location on maps. but i can able to displaying the map's using Xamarin.Forms.
Here is my Code

```
var map = new Map(
MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
new Position(17.3660, 78.4760), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
{
     IsShowingUser = true,
     HeightRequest = 100,
     WidthRequest = 960,
     VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
 };
 var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
 stack.Children.Add(map);
 Content = stack;
```

My out put

[image]

here i want to display the user current location.
this entire code was return in **Xamarin Shared code**.
i'm **not using Xamarin Android**.
can any one help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Most platforms require you to request permission to get a users location via GPS.

For Android this is located in the Android Manifest (under project properties). Check both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug on Android. It's working fine on iOS.

Here's the link to the [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21722) on bugzilla.

A possible workaround would be to show a map pin instead for as long as the bug hasn't been fixed. It goes like this:

```
map.Pins.Add(new Pin { Label = "You are here",
                       Position = new Position(17.3660, 78.4760) });
```

**UPDATE: This issue has been fixed on Xamarin.Forms.Maps version 1.3.0.6292.**